# if $4x-3$ is a factor of $4x^3-23x^2+px+27$ what is the value of $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm totally confused and I just started this class so I would love some help with steps. I tried long division and I'm aware that its $x^2-5x-9$ and I got $p=-21$ but I just used trial and error for it to work and I'm not sure if that would be graded in my finals, can anyone give me an explanation as to how you would get $-21$ using step by step instructions or links to videos with similar problems because this was honestly just luck and I wont have time to use trial and error in an exam

Comment: Hint: calculate, in two different ways, what you get when you plug in $x=\frac34$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the polynomial remainder theorem?

Comment: If $4x-3$ is a factor of $P(x)=4x^3-23x^2+px+27$ then $P(\frac{3}{4})=0$

Comment: $p=-21$ You can use the fact that the remainder is zero to calculate $p$ by [long division](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/long-division-of-polynomials/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe helpful for an overview: let $4x-3 = y$ and the polynomial becomes, after replacing $x = (3+y)/4$ and expanding,
$p(y/4 + 3/4) + y^3/16 - (7 y^2)/8 - (111 y)/16 + 63/4$. You want $y$ to be a divisor of this, which gives the remainder $p(3/4) + 63/4 = 0$ or $p = -21$. Admittedly, this is long division in disguise, however the effect can be seen immediately.